# How to use Social-Auth-Django-App with Facebook's https://m.me/

Tags: django, facebook

I tried using hyperlink and supplied it with my actual Facebook Username and it's working. But the problem is my actual Facebook Username is different from the Username provided by Social-Auth-App-Django. So I tried User ID instead but it's not working either.

By the way what I'm trying to do is an online shopping website and when a user clicks the hyperlink, he/she will be redirected to the seller's Facebook Messenger account to start a conversation.

This is the first line of code that I tried which is working.

```
<a href="https://m.me/myFacebookUsername">Send Message to Seller</a>
```

And this is the code I used using Social-Auth-App's provided data:

```
<a href="https://m.me/SocialAuth_Username">Send Message to Seller</a>
```

And I also tried this:

```
<a href="https://m.me/SocialAuth_UID">Send Message to Seller</a>
```

Any idea how I can use Facebook's m.me/ using the provided data by Social-Auth-App-Django? Or if you can suggest me other ways other than m.me/ I will greatly appreciate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can not get Facebook user names via API any more.

Comment: Is there any way I can do what I need then? Or it's not possible?

Comment: To link to a profile you ask for a link through the API.

Answer (score 0):

First Go To Setting.py And Put This Code End Of All Codes:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
]
```

Second Go To FaceBook Developer In This Address :
https://developers.facebook.com

And Make One Account There.
After go To My Apps And Then Click On Create App And Then Put Your Website Name ((Attention...If You Use Your Local Host You Need To Put One Domain Name For Your Local Ip)) And Your Email And Click On Create App ID And In Your Dashboard Looking For Facebook Login And Click On Set Up .
And Then In First Step In Web Window Put Your WebSite Name For Local Host For Example Put mysite.com:8000/ And Click On Save And Other Options Just Cross .
Now In Your Dashboard On The Left Side Click On Setting And Then Basic If You See Your APP ID And Your APP SECRET Put This Two In Your Settings.py After That Last Code .

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'Put Your App Id Code Here'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'Put Your App Secret Code Here'
```

If You Want To Take User's Email Also You Can You This As Well .

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
```

Now In You Dashboard Go To Settings And After Go To Basic An In Field App Domains Put Your Website Name Also Go To Settings After Advanced And Put Website Name In Domain Manager With CLick On Add a Domain .

Now Again In Dashboar Go In Products+ Part And Click On Facrbook Login After Settings And Check These Option Be Active(Yes) :

• Client OAuth Login
• Web OAuth Login
• Enforce HTTPS
• Embedded Browser OAuth Login

And IN This Form Your Are Now Also Go In This Field Valid OAuth Redirect URIs And Put This URL :
exapmle.com/social-auth/complete/facebook/

And Put Your Button In Your Website Page That Have This Login Auth :

```
<li>
     <a href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook" %}">Sign in with Facebook</a>
</li>
```